# Integrate stiff ODEs with Java

Tags: java, ode

Are there any free, open-source stiff integrator libraries for Java?

I am currently using the Dormand-Prince 8(5,3) integrator from the Apache Commons Math Library. I am implementing a DAE approximation for my model so I can use this integrator, but I would be interested in trying a stiff solver on the straight ODE system for comparison.

I have searched around but can't seem to find any straight answers. Something similar to the ode15s solver in MATLAB for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all of the solvers in the [Apache Commons Math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/ode/package-summary.html) are mainly for non-stiff problems. [`DormandPrince853Integrator`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/ode/nonstiff/DormandPrince853Integrator.html) is a good general choice, but even for mildly stiff problems it may not perform well.

You might look for implementations of [LSODE/ODEPACK](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/odepack/) or call a C or FORTRAN version of this directly. The open source Matlab alternative, [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), uses [`lsode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Ordinary-Differential-Equations.html) for solving ODEs (there are a couple R and Python interfaces as well).

You can read about the algorithms behind Matlab's [`ode15s`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15s.html) and other methods in this paper:

> L. F. Shampine and M. W. Reichelt, "The MATLAB ODE Suite", SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing, 18-1, 1997, [PDF link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/ode_suite.pdf), DOI: [10.1137/S1064827594276424](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S1064827594276424)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have looked at this website: http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/solveode.shtml , It has a C implementation of lsoda. Would a Java implementation of this be significantly slower? Would it make more sense to just setup an interface between the solver in C/FORTRAN and Java?

Answer (score 1):

Based on horchler's answer you might take a look at [JavaOdeInt](https://github.com/fons/JavaOdeInt)
 which offers an  interface to Fortran based solvers.